# gnutls-available-p is void despite emacs being built with gnutls

Tags: init-file, gnutls

I am attempting to secure my emacs 28.1 following the well-known guide [here](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2015/11/editor-malware.html#fnref:4:editor-malware-2015-11). After running into a (seemingly common) error with the bad certificate check I was lead to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18079/emacs-tls-check-is-still-ill-configured) emacs stackexchange post. The solution, allegedly, was to add the following lines to the intialization `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(if (fboundp 'gnutls-available-p)
    (fmakunbound 'gnutls-available-p))
```

However, I am unable to get this to work. I ran `M-x eval-expression` and did `(message system-configuration-options)` which gave me `--with-gnutls=yes`.

But when I do `M-x eval-expression` and do `(gnutls-available-p)` I get an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function gnutls-available-p)
  (gnutls-available-p)
  eval((gnutls-available-p) t)
  eval-expression((gnutls-available-p) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (gnutls-available-p) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression record nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "eval-expression" "eval-expression")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "eval-expression" "eval-expression")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how this function is void as it should be defined in my case. Confirming this I see `M-x eval-expression` with `(fboundp 'gnutls-available-p)` is `nil`. I also attempted to evaluate the conditional and got `nil` as a response.

So it seems that a function I expect is unbound. But, when evaluated with `fboundp` I at least don't get an error. Further, it seems that the condition *only* fails to work in the `init.el`. Is there a `require` I am missing that may help me here? I've been at this an hour and cannot work around it.

Comment: Does the `configure` output (before running `make`) when building Emacs from source indicate that  `gnutls` is present/detected?

Comment: Well, you yourself undefined it with that `(fmakunbound 'gnutls-available-p)`, so of course Emacs is going to complain about a void-function when you try to call it. It seems to me that the advice in the second link is more than a little bogus.